# Please explain what this notation means in K-means clustering.

Tags: notation, machine-learning

I am reading up on K-means clustering. I understand the procedure to an extent (I think!), but I am looking to understand the mathematical formulation better.

Given $m $ data points {$ x^1, x^2, ....., x^m $} $\in  \mathbb{R^n} $

Find $k $ cluster centers {$ c^1, c^2, ....., c^k $} $\in  \mathbb{R^n} $

And assign each data point i to one cluster

$\pi(i) \in $ {$ 1,2, ......,k$}

Such that, averaged square distance is minimized from each data point to respective cluster center.

$ min_{c, \pi}  \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^{m} \Vert x^i - c^{\pi(i)} \Vert^2$

Now, decide cluster membership of each data point $x^i$ by assigning it to nearest cluster.

$ \pi(i) = argmin_{j=1,.....,k} \Vert x^i - c^j \Vert^2$

```
Now what I don't understand is the following:

To update the cluster center we use:
```

> $c^j = \frac{1}{ \vert \{i:  \pi(i)=j  \} \vert } \sum_{i: \pi(i)=j}{x^i}$

I understand that we are averaging all the data points and selecting the new average as the cluster center, but how does this notation explain that? I would greatly appreciate if someone explained that to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\pi$ function tells you which cluster a data-point belongs to, so $\{i\colon \pi(i)=j\}$ denotes the (index) set of all points which belong to the $j$-th cluster. In particular

$$ c^j = \Big( \underbrace{\vert \{i:  \pi(i)=j  \} \vert}_{\substack{\text{number of data-points}\\\text{belonging to cluster j}} }\Big)^{-1} \underbrace{\sum_{i: \pi(i)=j}}_{{\substack{\text{sum over all data-points}\\\text{belonging to cluster j}}}}{x^i} $$

is the average of all data points beloning to the $j$-th cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please tell me, how you would go about reading the set expression in English? Like for example, "the set of all i when p-i equals the jth cluster", something like this? Sorry if this sounds mundane. Thanks

Comment: @Rio1210 The set $\{i:\pi(i)=j\}$ by itself would be  "The set of all $i$ such that $\pi$ of $i$ equals $j$". But imho it makes more sense to be a bit more verbose with respect to what it actually represents and call it "the (index) set of all points which belong to the $j$-th cluster".